# como reemplazar substrings por posiciones

Tags: java, string

tengo el problema que quiero reemplazar posiciones de una cadena a través de substrings, buscando la posición origen y posición final. Pero me reemplaza toda la cadena cuando tiene los mismos dígitos en este caso 0.

```
public class Prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String reemplazo;
        String identificador;
        String reemplazar;

        String price = "13440000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";

        identificador = price.substring(0, 4);
        identificador = price.replaceAll(identificador, "6666");

        reemplazo = price.substring(37, 39).toString();
        reemplazo = price.replaceAll(reemplazo, "BB");

        System.out.println(identificador);
        System.out.println(reemplazo);

    }

}
```

El primero que se llama `identificador` no tiene problemas.
El segundo me reemplaza por la cadena BB todos los 0 y yo solo necesito los 0 de la posición 37 hasta la 39.

Salida:

`66660000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1344BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB`

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Eso te pasa porque el 1344 solo lo tienes repetido una vez en la cadena, sino lo haría igual de mal que la segunda vez. Si replaceAll lo ejecutas sobre toda la cadena, te lo hará en toda la cadena, no en donde hiciste el substring en la línea anterior. No se si me explico. Buscas lo que hay del 37 al 39, qeu serán ceros, y le dices que  sustituya en la cadena original cada dos ceros por dos B, total, todos los ceros pasan a ser B

Comment: gracias por la explicación, te agradecería si podrias darme un ejemplo.

Comment: Dado que las cadenas en java no se pueden cambiar, tendrás que crearte una nueva copiando lo que hay hasta la posición 36, poner tus dos B, saltarte esos dos caracteres de la original, y copiar el resto. Al final es lo que hace replaceAll, crear un String nuevo con los cambios.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String price = "13440000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";

    identificador = price.substring(0, 4); -> Identificador vale 1344
    identificador = price.replaceAll(identificador, "6666"); -> reemplaza todas las veces que encuentres 1344, por 6666

    reemplazo = price.substring(37, 39).toString(); -> reemplazo vale 000
    reemplazo = price.replaceAll(reemplazo, "BB"); -> reemplaza todas las veces que encuentres 000 por BB.
```

Debido a lo anterior, para reemplazar en base a índices, puedes utilizar StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
sb.setCharAt(37, 'B');
str = sb.toString();
```